# install printer

Tags: printing

when my printer quit I purchased a new HP printer and connected it to my computer without
even thinking. A message came on the screen saying "Linux not supported". And that's when the fun started. The printer was new in the box but could have been a previous model. Since
my old one was about 20 years old I didn't give it a second thought til now. Thinking HP
could have developed new drivers I gave them a call. After over 2 hours on the phone I gave
up, wen't to Microcenter and bought a new one. Had trouble setting it up. Skipping details,4 printers later, 1 or 2 which don't do Linux. I now have a Brother HL-L2350DW which says it does recognize Linux but I can't install it on my 20.04. I found how to's
on line but the number of steps to do it I'd have to print them out. ...yup.
Does anybody out there have any suggestions?

Comment: Some years ago HP bought another printer company. These printers are now sold as HP branded printer. They don't have Linux drivers. It is not clear what you are asking. Are you having problem setting up the new Brother printer? Or are you asking for printer recommendation?

Comment: As for priming instructions you could print from a (smart) phone. Or go to Kinko's or to a friend's house.

Comment: Return the incompatible hardware. Avoid paying money for hardware that is incompatible with Linux. That simply rewards the manufacturer for the hassle they created. See the Openprinting.org database of linux-compatible printers: https://openprinting.org/printers

Comment: I have a similar printer `HL-L2370DW` and I was able to set it up with Xubuntu 20.04. Please see my question and answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397171/unable-to-work-with-brother-hl-l2370dw-printer-after-the-xubuntu-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

**Same here but something worked for me:**
I first tried to supress the printer many times, purge CUPS many times too, nothing changed. I ended up with a printer present in the system's parameters, but the printer showed "inactive". The print job was there but nothing happens. **So what I did:**

1. I installed the patch from this Brother website page (my printer is a L-L2350DW)
   https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj1205w_us&faqid=faq00100729_000
2. As it said, I installed the .deb file
   in a terminal:

   *dpkg -i brotherlegacyusb-1.1.0-0.all.deb*

unplugged the USB cable, wait a few seconds, replug it.

3. I erase the printer present in the system, reinstalled it **by the green button** (in Ubuntu 20.04, I had to click this green button only,).
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyY2d.jpg
4. Under the printer's frame, click "More parameters", opens up a small window, right-click on the printer's icon "Properties"
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTilu.jpg
5. A window opens, in left panel, 1st line "Parameters", right frame, "Manufacturer and model" (thie field showed "Generic Printer"), click "Modify", then I chose the model (I previousely had downloaded the driver from Brother site so my specific printer appeared on the list). Then the right model is shown in the field.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/upH4X.jpg

I test a print and it worked right away, no restart.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan.
- Move on to https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/.
- Download and install ipp-usb and sane-airscan.
- Disconnect and reconnect to USB.
- Printing and scanning should be immediately available.